# Multiple contexts per application vs multiple applications per context

Tags: performance, opengl, optimization, scenegraph

I was wondering whether it is a good idea to create a "system" wide rendering server that is responsible for the rendering of all application elements. Currently, applications usually have their own context, meaning whatever data might be identical across different applications, it will be duplicated in GPU memory and the more frequent resource management calls only decrease the count of usable render calls. From what I understand, the OpenGL execution engine/server itself is sequential/single threaded in design. So technically, everything that might be reused across applications, and especially heavy stuff like bitmap or geometry caches for text and UI, is just clogging the server with unnecessary transfers and memory usage.

Are there any downsides to having a scenegraph shared across multiple applications? Naturally, assuming the correct handling of clients which accidentally freeze.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering whether it is a good idea to create a "system" wide rendering server that is responsible for the rendering of all application elements.

That depends on the task at hand. A small detour: Take a webbrowser for example, where JavaScript performs manipulations on the DOM; CSS transform and SVG elements define graphical elements. Each JavaScript called in response to an event may run as a separate thread/lighweight process. In a matter of sense the webbrowser is a rendering engine (heck they're internally even called rendering engines) for a whole bunch of applications.

And for that it's a good idea.

And in general display servers are a very good thing. Just have a look at X11, which has an incredible track record. These days Wayland is all the hype, and a lot of people drank the Kool-Aid, but you actually want the abstraction of a display server. **However not for the reasons you thought.** The main reason to have a display server is to avoid redundant code (not redundant data) and to have only a single entity to deal with the dirty details (color spaces, device physical properties) and provide optimized higher order drawing primitives.

#### But in regard with the direct use of OpenGL none of those considerations matter:

> Currently, applications usually have their own context, meaning whatever data might be identical across different applications,

So? Memory is cheap. And you don't gain performance by coalescing duplicate data, because the only thing that matters for performance is the memory bandwidth required to process this data. But that bandwidth doesn't change because it only depends on the internal structure of the data, which however is unchanged by coalescing.

In fact deduplication creates significant overhead, since when one application made changes, that are not to affect the other application a copy-on-write operation has to be invoked which is not for free, usually means a full copy, which however means that while making the whole copy the memory bandwidth is consumed.

However for a small, selected change in the data of one application, with each application having its own copy the memory bus is blocked for much shorter time.

> it will be duplicated in GPU memory and the more frequent resource management calls only decrease the count of usable render calls.

Resource management and rendering normally do not interfere with each other. While the GPU is busy turning scalar values into points, lines and triangles, the driver on the CPU can do the housekeeping. In fact a lot of performance is gained by keeping making the CPU do non-rendering related work while the GPU is busy rendering.

> From what I understand, the OpenGL execution engine/server itself is sequential/single threaded in design

Where did you read that? There's no such constraint/requirement on this in the OpenGL specifications and real OpenGL implementations (=drivers) are free to parallelize as much as they want.

> just clogging the server with unnecessary transfers and memory usage.

Transfer happens only once, when the data gets loaded. Memory bandwidth consumption is unchanged by deduplication. And memory is so cheap these days, that data deduplication simply isn't worth the effort.

> Are there any downsides to having a scenegraph shared across multiple applications? Naturally, assuming the correct handling of clients which accidentally freeze.

I think you completely misunderstand the nature of OpenGL. **OpenGL is not a scene graph**. There's no scene, there are mo models in OpenGL. Each applications has its own layout of data and eventually this data gets passed into OpenGL to draw pixels onto the screen.

To OpenGL however there are just drawing commands to turn arrays of scalar values into points, lines and triangles on the screen. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: There are many mobile devices with 1 GB of memory or less, which is shared between the CPU and GPU.

Comment: Also, I never made a claim that OpenGL is a scenegraph. The question is whether using a shared sceengraph is a good idea to maximize GL calls.

Comment: @user2341104: It always depends on the application. For a complex GUI system (ATM I and a few friends from the local hackerspace are dabbling with that) would certainly benefit from a shared display server. However visualization systems or games will actually have their performance impaired. Also shared scene graphs open a huge can of worms regarding security and data separation. When it comes to memory, except for games, visualization and image/video editing most applications require only a couple of 100kiB, maybe a few MiB top.